# Como hacer una función que haga clic en determinados puntos de la pagina web en secuencia?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

espero entiendan lo que quiero hacer pues recuerdo que hace unos años inventando conseguí algo parecido que hacia clic en determinado punto de la pagina y recuerdo que había que colocarle los pixeles exactos de el lugar donde iba a hacer clic, quiero hacer lo mismo pero no consigo algo parecido.

Quiero hacer lo mismo pero esta vez con 2 clics, ejemplo: al cargar la pagina en 5 segundos después haga clic en un determinado punto de la pagina como si estuviese el puntero alli, y luego a los 10 segundos hacer otro clic similar pero en otro punto determinado.! gracias espero haberme explicado

Comment: Hola estas tratando de automatizar? Hay muchas herramientas para eso como [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/), [Karate](https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/), [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/), entre varias otras... Herramientas como estas te permiten hacer click identificando tags html por **id** o por **xpath** en lugar de indicar pixel por pixel. Tambien puedes cargar formularios y otra cosa que quieres hacer, puedes esperar un tiempo o esperar a que algo suceda para que hagas click.

Comment: Solo necesito que se hagan esos 2 clics me gustaría hacerlo como antes pues cumpliría lo que quiero hacer, algún código que con indicarle los pixeles exactos hiciera clic ahí en determinado tiempo gracias andres

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Recuerda aportar un [mcve] para poder ayudarte a resolver el problema. Por cierto, ¿cuál es el problema concreto? Si estás pidiendo recomendaciones, tu pregunta entonces se basa en opiniones, motivo por el cual terminaría cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Amigo he estado buscando por todos lados aqui consegui a una persona con el mismo problema que tal vez lo explica mejor que yo: Necesito un script que cuando se cargue mi página web, se haga un click automáticamente en un enlace de otra web que la tengo metida como iframe.

Es decir, tengo una web A y otra web B.

En la web A, tengo un iframe de B.

Cuanto cargue la web A, se debe hacer un click automáticamente en una imagen que aparece en el iframe de la web B.

No tengo acceso a la web B, solo a la web A.