# Hacer clic automático por coordenadas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Tengo el siguiente problema a ver si alguien me puede dar un poco de luz en el asunto.

El propósito es que al entrar a una pagina web, al cabo de unos segundos se haga un click (click de mouse) automáticamente sobre las coordenadas X Y deseadas.

Por ahora lo he conseguido hacer sobre un botón de un formulario:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script> $(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(clickbutton,5000); function clickbutton() {
$("#botonEnviar").click(); } });
</script>
```

```html
<form action="http://www.xxx.com"> <input type="submit" id="botonEnviar" value="enviar formulario"> </form>
```

Pero no me sirve, pero como he visto que esto funciona y también que se pueden obtener la coordenadas mediante javascript, tal vez se pueda hacer el click automático de ese modo.

Comment: Lo tienes complicado, el `mouse` no es algo que puedas controlar directamente con Javascript, lo que puedes hacer es simular eventos sobre determinados elementos, ya te [sugirieron](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389188/como-hacer-una-funci%c3%b3n-que-haga-clic-en-determinados-puntos-de-la-pagina-web-en#comment697126_389188) en esta [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/389188/como-hacer-una-funci%c3%b3n-que-haga-clic-en-determinados-puntos-de-la-pagina-web-en) pregunta que usaras algún tipo de herramienta para automatizar procesos.

Answer (score 3):

Podes despachar un evento de click en una coordenada específica con

```javascript
document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
```

Aunque esto no es lo mismo que un clic real: Por ejemplo, no se puede utilizar para engañar a un documento iframe de dominios cruzados haciéndole creer que se hizo clic en él.

[Mas información](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint)